# Conditional dependency ignored in mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, requirejs

In the midst of building a site, we've run into a conflict between VideoJS and Angular, such that Angular modules won't load in iOS7 when the VideoJS library is present. This is one hell of an edge case, and page content is *much* more important than a peripheral video, so we're opting to just nix VideoJS for our mobile users and use an image fallback.

Now, consider this relevant code excerpt from a requirejs module:

```
log("checkpoint 1");

var videojs, $ = require('jquery');

if($(".home").length && $(window).outerWidth() > 768){
    log("checkpoint 2a");
    videojs = require('videojs');
    log("checkpoint 2b");

    // video init code here
}

log("checkpoint 3");
```

In any mobile device, the log returns:

```
> checkpoint 1
> checkpoint 3
```

which indicates that the loop isn't penetrated in mobile, as expected. However, contrary to this, the videojs library is still being loaded - which defeats the whole purpose of conditionally including it.

We've confirmed that this is the only place the videojs library is being included, as the problem disappears when `videojs = require('videojs');` is commented out - the library does not appear in the resources list, and the page renders normally.

Are we just setting up the conditional dependency poorly? Is there another way we can execute this, or are we stuck firmly in a known limitation of Require?

Answer (score 0):

```
videojs = require('videojs')
```

I'll bet this is a line in a source (non-compiled file) that you then compile with browserify (or something similar before you release your app).

The problem is, of course, that your compiled files will ALWAYS require videojs (unless the line is commented out) because your conditional is based on determinants only available at run-time, not compile-time.

So, to answer your question:

> Are we just setting up the conditional dependency poorly?

yes.

There are probably a bunch of ways to do this, but one that comes to my mind is to serve the videojs library as a separate asset. You'd use (ugh) User Agent parsing to determine if the device is running `iOS7` something like the following (PHP example):

```
<?php if(!is_ios7()) { //pseudo code - UA parsing in here. ?>
 <script src="/path/to/videojs"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

And then in your main js file you can just detect if the videojs globals are present and then use it if required.

Answer (score -1):

for production and test ENV and for mobile/desktop vertion use can use this loader:(from this git hub project https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Marionette-Require-Boilerplate/blob/master/public/index.html )

```
    // Mobile/Desktop Detection script
            (function(ua, w, d, undefined) {
                // App Environment
                // ---------------
                //  Tip: Set to true to turn on "production" mode
                var production = true,
                        filesToLoad,
                //BoilerplateMVC Helper Methods
                        boilerplateMVC = {
                            loadCSS: function(url, callback) {
                                var link = d.createElement("link");
                                link.type = "text/css";
                                link.rel = "stylesheet";
                                link.href = url;
                                d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
                                if(callback) {
                                    callback();
                                }
                            },
                            loadJS: function(file, callback) {
                                var script = d.createElement("script");
                                script.type = "text/javascript";
                                if (script.readyState) {  // IE
                                    script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                        if (script.readyState == "loaded"
 || script.readyState == "complete") {
                                            script.onreadystatechange = null;
                                            callback();
                                        }
                                    };
                                } else {  // Other Browsers
                                    script.onload = function() {
                                        callback();
                                    };
                                }
                                if(((typeof file).toLowerCase()) === "object"
 && file["data-main"] !== undefined) {
                                    script.setAttribute("data-main", 
file["data-main"]);
                                    script.async = true;
                                    script.src = file.src;
                                } else {
                                    script.src = file;
                                }
                                d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
                            },
                            loadFiles: function(production, obj, callback) {
                                var self = this;
                                if(production) {
                                    // Loads the production CSS file(s)
                                    self.loadCSS(obj["prod-css"], function() {
                                        // If there are production JavaScript files to load
                                        if(obj["prod-js"]) {
                                            // Loads the correct initialization file (which includes Almond.js)
                                            self.loadJS(obj["prod-js"], callback);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // Loads the development CSS file(s)
                                    self.loadCSS(obj["dev-css"], function() {
                                        // If there are development Javascript files to load
                                        if(obj["dev-js"]) {
                                            // Loads Require.js and tells Require.js to find the correct intialization file
                                            self.loadJS(obj["dev-js"], callback);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        };
                // Mobile/Tablet Logic
                if((/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/).test(ua)) {
                    // Mobile/Tablet CSS and JavaScript files to load
                    filesToLoad = {
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-css": "css/mobile.css",
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-css": "css/mobile.min.css",
                        // Require.js configuration file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" },
                        // JavaScript initialization file that is also loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-init": "js/app/init/MobileInit.js",
                        // JavaScript file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-init": "js/app/init/MobileInit.min.js",
                        "prod-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" }
                    };
                }
                // Desktop Logic
                else {
                    // Desktop CSS and JavaScript files to load
                    filesToLoad = {
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-css": "css/desktop.css",
                        // CSS file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-css": "css/desktop.min.css",
                        // Require.js configuration file that is also loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" },
                        // JavaScript initialization file that is loaded when in development mode
                        "dev-init": "js/app/init/DesktopInit.js",
                        // JavaScript file that is loaded when in production mode
                        "prod-init": "js/app/init/DesktopInit.min.js",
                        "prod-js": { "data-main": "js/app/config/config.js", "src": "js/libs/require.js" }
                    };
                }
                boilerplateMVC.loadFiles(production, filesToLoad, function() {
                    if(!production && window.require) {
                        require([filesToLoad["dev-init"]]);
                    } else if ( production ) {
                        require([filesToLoad["prod-init"]])
                    }
                });
            })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, window, document);
```

and onother logic in this project :

```
    var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    function isMobile() {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        return ((/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|Opera Mini|IEMobile/).test(userAgent));
    }

    App.mobile = isMobile();


require(["App", "jquery", "routers/AppRouter", "controllers/MobileController", "backbone", "marionette", "jquerymobile", "backbone.validateAll"],
    function (App, $, AppRouter, AppController) {
        // Prevents all anchor click handling
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

        App.appRouter = new AppRouter({
            controller:new AppController()
        });

        App.start();
    });
```